# Celery Worker with multiple processors, but single task

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, celery

I want to have a Celery worker that has access to multiple threads to run a program that is multiple threaded, but I don't want it to pick up a second job.

We have a python program that includes two threads that is launched by RabbitMQ/celery.

Each  box has multiple processors.  I have one worker on each box, and it should access all processors.  `--concurrency` of one seems to stop additional threads from being available, which stops the second thread from launching.  `--concurrency` of more than one means that it'll pick up additional jobs.

This code launches a second thread.

I think I should be able to pick some combination of
`--pool` and `--concurrency` settings that would allow multiple threads to a worker, but I'm not sure which.

```
import threading
import time
import os


class im_watching():
    def watcher_thread(self, done = False):
        with open(self.filen, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write("I am watching\n")
            print("I am watching " + str(time.time()))
        x = 0
        while not done:
            with open(self.filen, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                x = x+1
                f.write("I am still watching\n")
            if x == 7:
                done = True
        
        with open(self.filen, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write("I am done\n")

    def print_time(self):
        self.filen = 'threadfile_celery.txt'
        with open(self.filen, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write('0: ' + str(time.time())+ '\n')
        print(time.time())
        x = threading.Thread(target=self.watcher_thread, daemon=True)
        x.start()
        print(time.time())
        r = range (10)
        for i in r:
            with open(self.filen, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.write(str(i+1)+ ' ' + str(time.time())+ '\n')
```

Then we run it

```
@app.task   
def check_thread():
    import thread_watch as tw
    tp = tw.im_watching()
    tp.print_time()
```

When run without celery, we see this.

> 0: 1660249134.2473516
> 1 1660249134.2533522
> I am watching
> 2 1660249134.2653418
> I am still watching
> 3 1660249134.268349
> I am still watching
> 4 1660249134.272345
> I am still watching
> 5 1660249134.2753484
> 6 1660249134.278356
> I am still watching
> 7 1660249134.2803547
> I am still watching
> 8 1660249134.2833555
> I am still watching
> 9 1660249134.2993486
> 10 1660249134.3043566
> I am still watching
> I am done

With celery, it prints this, which seems like its not threading.

> 0: 1660249011.9372554
> I am watching
> I am still watching
> I am still watching
> I am still watching
> I am still watching
> I am still watching
> I am still watching
> I am still watching
> I am done
> 1 1660249011.9562619
> 2 1660249011.9582546
> 3 1660249011.960263
> 4 1660249011.9622533
> 5 1660249011.964253
> 6 1660249011.9652538
> 7 1660249011.9672582
> 8 1660249011.9692612
> 9 1660249011.971259
> 10 1660249011.9732592

Comment: I don't think I quite understand. If your task code leverages multiple cores, that's all you need. Celery doesn't impose any limits on how many cores _your_ code can access. The `--concurrency` and `--pool` flags are for the internal processes used by celery. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Python uses cooperative multitasking. Although you can have multiple theads, only one thread will run at a time. This is control via the python Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). Only code that specifically releases the GIL can work in parallel - and regular python code can't do that. If you see only one processor being used, that;s the issue.

Comment: @sytech, we find that when we launch this program locally, the second thread launches fine.   It's a watcher thread that checks to see if a file exists.  When we launch the same program via celery with a concurrency of 1, it doesn't launch the watcher thread.  I assumed it was due to the --pool and --concurrency settings, but it sounds like that's the wrong place to look?

Comment: Hmm. I don't think the pool and concurrency are the right places to look. Although, a concurrency setting of `1` is kind of odd to do and depending on what your task does, could easily result in a deadlock. How do you know your task is not launching the watcher thread? Do you have logging in the thread? What is happening after you call `.start()` for the thread? Can you share the code for `watcher_thread` and your entire task?

Comment: Or better, a fake small minimal boring task that shows the same problem.

Comment: We have the watcher task print something when it starts up, and the print statement didn't produce anything.    We will rework the code into a boring minimal task.